# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Selection.InsertFile() Method->How to use Bookmark in Range Parameter

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

We're doing an update to an MS Word Add-In that allows users to insert MS Word files into a central MS Word document by using the following function:

```
 //Created rng variable
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
//MS Interop method.
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InsertFile(
     filename,
     rng,//<--Added range                              
     ref missing, //Confirm Conversions
     ref falsevalue, //Link file
     ref falsevalue //Attachment
);
```

The second parameter:

```
ref missing, //Range - For Word can be a bookmark
```

Seems to say that we can pass a Range parameter that can be a bookmark (which we 
     can use to delete the added content, if needed), however we haven't been able to find any implementation examples that demonstrate how this is done.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertfile.aspx) describes this parameter as follows:

---

***Range***

***Type: System.Object***

***Optional Object.***

***If the specified file is a Word document, this parameter refers to a bookmark. If the file is another type (for example, a Microsoft Excel worksheet), this parameter refers to a named range or a cell range (for example, R1C1:R3C4).***

---

Since we want to insert a new bookmark with the text, we assumed that we need to:

1. Create a new bookmark, and
2. Pass it into the InsertFile parameter list

However at this point, since we can't find any examples of how this is achieved, we're at a stopping point.

We also found examples such as these:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.bookmark.bookmarks(v=vs.120).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-replace-and-remove-bookmarks-in-word-using-c-sharp/

But it doesn't look like their implementations are using Word Interop or Selection.InsertFile().

Intellisense doesn't seem to indicate a Range property on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks (your fist link) are a collection of [Bookmark](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.bookmark_members.aspx) objects. Bookmark has a Range property. Use that.

Comment: I think the link you included refers to Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word and not Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.  We're using Interop.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. I now have the link to the interop Bookmark object. Same answer, use Bookmark.Range.

Comment: I added  
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Bookmark.Range doesn't seem to be available as shown in the screen shot above.)
Then used that parameter as shown in my edited post.

Getting this error:
"Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"

Answer (score -1):

> Type: System.Object
>
> Optional Object.
>
> If **the specified file** is a Word document, this parameter refers to a
>   bookmark. If the file is another type (for example, a Microsoft Excel
>   worksheet), this parameter refers to a named range or a cell range
>   (for example, R1C1:R3C4).

Meant is a bookmark or range identifier of the inserted file.

**@Edit:**

In case you search a solution to insert files in a existing bookmark without delete the bookmark, try this:

```
var bmRange = bookmark.Range;
string bookmarkName = bookmark.Name;

// plus 1 on the end prevents startRange to collapse on insert.
// be shure there is something after the end
var startRange = document.Range(bmRange.Start, bmRange.End + 1);

object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object ConfirmConversions = false;
object Link = false;
object Attachment = false;
bmRange.InsertFile("C:\\somefile.docx", ref missing, ref ConfirmConversions, ref Link, ref Attachment);

// after insert the startRange contains the inserted content + 1
var newRange = document.Range(startRange.Start, startRange.End - 1);
document.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, ref newRange);
```

with a little modification (you only have to get the bmRange and bookmarkName  from somewhere else) this should work also without an exisiting bookmark

**@Edit2:**
Remanufactored to Extension Method for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document:

```
public static void ReplaceBookmarkContentWithFile(this Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document, string path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range, string bookmarkName)
{
    var startRange = document.Range(range.Start, range.End + 1);

    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object ConfirmConversions = false;
    object Link = false;
    object Attachment = false;
    range.InsertFile(path, ref missing, ref ConfirmConversions, ref Link, ref Attachment);

    object newRange = document.Range(startRange.Start, startRange.End - 1);
    document.Bookmarks.Add(bookmarkName, ref newRange);
}
```

Call it like:

```
document.ReplaceBookmarkContentWithFile(path, range, bookmarkName);
```

works for both ... exisiting Bookmark (if the range is the bookmark.Range) or not ;)